# Реализация таймаутов в epoll

Tags: c++, сокет, epoll

Подскажите, как реализовать таймауты соединений при использовании epoll? Требуется определять неактивные соединения и закрывать их.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так ведь в [man epoll_wait](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_wait) явно прописан timeout в миллисекундах.

Вот им и пользуйтесь. Если epoll_wait() вернул 0, то таймаут истек. В этом случае просматриваете свой вектор epoll_event, по которым делаете опрос и принимаете решение.

Видимо в вашем случае с каждым соединением надо связать структуру данных, что-то вроде

```
struct connect {
   int sock_fd;
   time_t last; // ???
   ...
};
```

а в struct epoll_event, массив которых передаете в epoll_wait() использовать  поле .data.ptr (заносите туда адрес соответствующей struct connect).

Соответственно, при каждом recv() меняете в нужном блоке last. А при таймауте сравнивает текущее время с каждым last.

Как-то так, если кратко.

Comment: И где-то на 10к сокетов он перестанет возвращать ноль. Но идея в принципе понятна. Я тоже склонялся к похожему решению, но там была идея лишь раз в 10 секунд проверять все соединения, что чточно не будет создавать нежелательной нагрузки, однако мне показали другое решение. Привел его в своем ответе.  К сожалению, пока не могу решить, какое решение лучше.

Comment: @mikelsv, ну вам же в любом случае надо пересчитывать передаваемый при *очередном* вызове в epoll_wait таймут (ведь обычно куча возвратов будет не с нулем). Так что, если очередной пересчитанный таймаут стал нулем, то настало время просмотра вектора events.

Comment: Сейчас нет, epoll_wait() вызывается с бесконечным ожиданием. Теперь же я скорее всего буду вызывать его с интервалом в 10 секунд. Пока не стоит задачи сделать точный таймаут.

Comment: @mikelsv, если у вас все таймауты одинаковы, то (наверное, такое решение Вы  тоже рассматривали) можно все делать за O(1). Используем самоорганизующийся двусвязный список connections. Новые добавляем в конец списка. Обновляемые (мы получаем из epoll_wait  сразу адрес элемента списка) перемещаем в конец списка с пересчитанным временем таймаута. Таким образом список всегда будет упорядочен по времени таймаута.  При поиске "просроченных" соединений  достаточно проверять элементы в голове списка (и сразу удалять их) пока время наступления таймаута меньше текущего. IMHO красиво.

Comment: Я тоже думал о таком красивом решении, но к сожалению концепция сервера такова, что таймауты могут быть разными. Конечно, можно ставить их в список с таймаутом в секунду и перебрасывать в конец списка, но это будет лишняя нагрузка, хотя тоже вроде вариант.  Перед решением этой проблемы требуется решить другую: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/429478 , как сказать епулу передать сокет в обработчик.

Comment: Вряд ли вариантов таймаутов много. Можно сделать несколько списков, по одному для каждого таймаута (их также можно адресовать через хэш-таблицу). А в структуре connect (чтобы не искать нужный список) надо сделать указатель на список в который она входит. Попробуйте, мне кажется из этого может получиться достойное решение. (если в самом деле окажется так, опубликуйте здесь, как ответ).

Answer (score 1):

Подобная проблема довольно интересно решена здесь: https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/src/epoll.cpp#L152 и https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/src/poller_base.cpp#L78 .

Если вкратце, то там берется std::multimap и, когда требуется установить таймер, в него записывают время срабатывания и указатель на класс, которому надо сообщить. И перед каждым вызовом epoll_wait() проверяется у кого истек таймер. Довольно интересное и быстрое решение.

Comment: Тут все зависит от *интенсивности* (частоты) вызовов epoll_wait. / Допустим, вы работаете с большим количеством активных соединений, а значит очень часто вызываете epoll_wait и каждый раз вам придется смотреть (почти всегда безрезультатно), а у кого истек таймаут. На самом деле это очень быстро. А вот обновление каждого таймера вызовет его удаление и последующую вставку в rb-tree (т.е. время порядка log(N)). / В моем ответе обновление -- быстро, просмотр (по таймауту, скажем на практике раз в секунду) время порядка N. / Пока все (отбываю до понедельника)

Comment: В принципе да, проще пробежаться по массиву элементов. Меня тоже смущала работа с динамическим массивом, к тому же пришлось бы переписать его так, чтобы он не дергал malloc() при каждом добавлении таймера.