# Использование epoll в многопоточном приложении

Tags: epoll

Есть концептуальный вопрос, на который мне необходимо найти ответ.

Введение: Я добавляю сокеты в epoll с флагом EPOLLONESHOT, который говорит, что этот сокет нужно выдать в `epoll_wait()` всего один раз. Приложение многопоточное и без этого флага сокет получит каждый поток.

Задача: требуется послать данные в сокет или закрыть его из постороннего потока.

Проблема: так как неизвестно состояние сокета: он может ждать в epoll или может быть выдан `epoll_wait()` в обработчик. То и производить операции с сокетом опасно, это может вызвать ошибки.

Вопрос: как добиться определенности состояния сокета и произвести операцию?

Решения:

1. Если добавить дополнительное значение, которое будет указывать, в каком состоянии находится сокет, то придется добавлять лишние критические секции, от которых я и так стараюсь избавиться. Так же потребуется написать хитрую логику.
2. Более правильным кажется решение сообщить в epoll, что состояние сокета изменилось, тогда он передаст сокет в обработчик. А обработчик уже разберестя, что с ним делать. Но как сказать epoll, чтобы он скинул сокет в обработчик?
3. Еще варианты?

Без решения этой проблемы у меня не выйдет нормального сервера.